# Google Cloud Storage authentication for App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We would like to start using Google Cloud Storage as a persistent store for user-uploaded files. Unfortunately, I can't add the App Identity (*application-id*@appspot.gserviceaccount.com) to our "Team" because our team is based on Google Apps for domains, and it does not allow any email addresses that are not on our domain to be on the team.

Is there a recommended way to authenticate the App Engine instance in this case?

Comment: Outta curiosity, what features are you grabbing from Cloud Storage that won't be accessible via App Engine + Blobstore?

Comment: We want to expose the data for users to download, and Cloud Storage is much faster and cheaper than serving it through appengine. Basically, we're using it as an easy-to-invalidate CDN.

Comment: Gotcha. We've had some good luck (performance wise) w/ sending back cache headers w/ our blobstore responses (Google's frontend servers seem to speedily handle most requests after that). The easy-to-invalidate part is a different story.

Comment: Did you get it to work?  Please share how you did it.

Comment: @Yasser, See the accepted answer.

Comment: @tghw you said you were going to use the REST API and not the hack so i was looking for that solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new team using a gmail account. Add all your team members (including the app), and delete the gmail account from the team.

Yes, it's a horrid hack. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

You can also work around this by using [GSUtil](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/docs/gsutil.html) to explicitly grant write access to the bucket you created so that your service account "application-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com" have sufficient access to the bucket. By default, your bucket can't be accessed by others.

What you will need to do with GSUtil to modify your ACL on the bucket is this:

- Retrieve the bucket's ACL: gsutil getacl gs://mybucket > acl.txt
- Make changes to acl.txt such as adding an additional grant for user "application-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com" to have write access of the bucket, see ACL doc. on how to do this: http://code.google.com/apis/storage/docs/accesscontrol.html#applyacls 
  Specifically, it might look something like this to add to the acl.txt you downloaded:

  ```xml
  <Entry>
    <Scope type="UserByEmail">
      <EmailAddress>application-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com</EmailAddress> 
      <Name>Service Account</Name> 
    </Scope> 
    <Permission>FULL_CONTROL</Permission> 
  </Entry>
  ```
- Update ACL on the bucket: gsutil setacl acl.txt gs://yourbucket

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did you actually try it, did it work?  The instructions specifically ask to add permissions to the project not the bucket:  'Add the service account as a project editor to the Google APIs Console project that the bucket belongs to'

Comment: This worked for me. I got the service account name from the App Engine console under "Application Settings".

Answer (score -1):

For using the Google Cloud Storage you can go through this link https://developers.google.com/storage/ and then create the new account then use.

Comment: That's not what was being asked here